# On Gentoo, what is loading up my network interfaces?

Tags: networking, gentoo

I have 2 networking interfaces `eth0` (wired) and `wlan0` (wireless). Every time the computer boots it tries to bring up both. Most often when there is a LAN cable I don't need `wlan0`, and vice versa, so this looks like a waste. I want to stop the interfaces from being brought up automatically so that I can bring up the one that I need, if at all.

According to the [Gentoo Handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?style=printable&full=1#book_part4_chap1__chap1_pre3) I need to run

```
# rc-update add net.eth0 default
```

to have `eth0` up every time the system boots and I assume the same thing goes for `wlan0`. However the result of

```
# rc-update show
```

does not contain either `eth0` or `wlan0`.

So the question is, who is bringing up the 2 interfaces? How can I stop that?

Answer (score 4):

Some services requires network service (i.e. they use the network ;) ). The `RC_NET_STRICT_CHECKING` variable from `/etc/conf.d/rc` determines when the service is 'up'. In particular, the "no" setting seems to describe something similar to what you want:

```
#  no    - This basically means that at least one net.* service besides net.lo
#          must be up.  This can be used by notebook users that have a wifi and
#          a static nic, and only wants one up at any given time to have the
#          'net' service seen as up.
```

I guess that configuration you described is particularly useful in mobile environments and, personally, I prefer to use net-misc/networkmanager to manage network for me and disable Gentoo script managing (which is mostly suitable for servers and have no proper handling of hibernation, dynamic configuration etc.).

Comment: I tried changing this variable around but it doesn't seem to make any difference. BTW how do you disable the script managing?

Comment: By removing `/etc/init.d/net.wlan0` and `/etc/init.d/net.eth0` (both are only symlinks to ``/etc/init.d/net.lo` so don't worry).

Comment: nice, I'll try that

Comment: `/etc/conf.d/rc` is deprecated and doesn't work anymore under the new baselayout-2/openrc boot system. `/etc/rc.conf` is the new equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I do this because I use NetworkManager to handle my connections, and I wanted to stop Gentoo from always trying and failing to get an IP through DHCP for my almost-always-unconnected `eth0`.

The following setting in `/etc/rc.conf/`:

```
rc_hotplug="!net.*"
```

stops Gentoo from trying to automagically start any of the `net.` services, but you can still manually add them to runlevels or directly call the `/etc/init.d/` scripts for them.

Answer (score -1):

Gentoo does device based services. There is a setting in if I `/etc/conf.d/rc` that allows you to override this. What you probably want to do is to use networkmanager which works nicely with laptops and their changing connectivity. There are some gentoo networkmanager manuals available just a google search away.